# Spring batch - restart failed read step

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I have a reader from HttpURLConnection that can sometimes produce 500 HTTP response. When this happens, job is FAILED and ItemStreamException: Failed to initialize the reader is thrown. Is there any way to automatically retry read step (since usually after 3 retries this endpoint will return 200 OK)?

I tried this but doesn't work:

```
return stepBuilderFactory.get("step4")
            .chunk(100)
            .reader(httpurlreader())
            .faultTolerant()
            .retry(ItemStreamException.class)
            .retryLimit(10)
            .listener(new RetryReadListenerAdapter(retryReadListener()))
            .writer(new someitemwriter())
            .build();
```

**UPDATE**

Ended up creating FaultTolerantItemStreamItemReaderWrapper which can wrap read operations and apply RetryTemplate on open method().

```
import org.springframework.batch.item.ExecutionContext;
import org.springframework.batch.item.support.AbstractItemStreamItemReader;
import org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate;

public class FaultTolerantItemStreamItemReaderWrapper<T> extends AbstractItemStreamItemReader<T> {

    private final AbstractItemStreamItemReader<T> itemStreamItemReader;
    private final RetryTemplate retryTemplate;

    public FaultTolerantItemStreamItemReaderWrapper(AbstractItemStreamItemReader<T> itemStreamItemReader, RetryTemplate retryTemplate) {
        this.itemStreamItemReader = itemStreamItemReader;
        this.retryTemplate = retryTemplate;
    }

    @Override
    public void close() {
        itemStreamItemReader.close();
    }

    @Override
    public void update(ExecutionContext executionContext) {
        itemStreamItemReader.update(executionContext);
    }

    @Override
    public void setName(String name) {
        itemStreamItemReader.setName(name);
    }

    @Override
    public String getExecutionContextKey(String key) {
        return itemStreamItemReader.getExecutionContextKey(key);
    }

    @Override
    public void open(ExecutionContext executionContext) {
        retryTemplate.execute(retryContext -> {
            itemStreamItemReader.open(executionContext);
            return null;
        });
    }

    @Override
    public T read() throws Exception {
        return itemStreamItemReader.read();
    }
}
```

And then I just call it normally in setup stage:

```
return stepBuilderFactory.get("step4")
        .chunk(100)
        .reader(new FaultTolerantItemStreamItemReaderWrapper<>(httpurlreader(), retryTemplate()))
        .writer(new someitemwriter())
        .build();
```

Comment: Use Spring Retry to do the actual launch.

Comment: Can you please give some sample code? If I use job listener and try to detect if job failed in order to restart it, it won't let starting it since it is not still stopped. The only solution i found is to wait X minutes, and then restart it programmaticaly, or restart it manually. Seems like there is no single source on net where it shows how to automatically restart completely failed job with some back-off strategy.

Comment: yes, there is no function in spring-batch that automatically restarts a failed job, because this is the task of a job-control system normally task. But as Micheal mentioned, there is the retry-mechanism. You can write your own RetryPolicy, or you can probably directly use the TimoutRetryPolicy that is provided in the framework.

Comment: Since I use TaskExecutor (to execute job async) - this RetryTemplate somehow doesn't work with it?